# The imagemap today

Tags: html, imagemap

Remember imagemaps from Web 0.9b? I'm curious about the state of this tag now in 2010.

Given some of the surprising and successful resurgences of white elephant technologies (Google Maps' use of Javascript, which was novel when it first appeared, and MySpace ushering in an animated GIF renaissance), is anyone using imagemaps today in new or interesting ways? How do they fare in current browsers, and do they play well with contemporary Javascript techniques or other new technologies?

Answer (score 1):

Image maps still work perfectly fine, but most web developers choose not to use them, preferring instead to have multiple images positioned using CSS (possibly with each image wrapped in an anchor tag or with javascript events attached).

Image maps were great in the days when CSS was poorly supported, but we don't need them anymore even though they still work fine. Using CSS on multiple images allows you to do everything you can do with image maps, and it's much more flexible.

For example, you can dynamically remove an individual img. With image maps you would have to replace the *entire* image to remove even one item in the map.

Comment: How about this one, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Club_(Literary_Club). The image won't change and isn't made from several images. Isn't this a good use of the the imagemap?

Comment: You could use an image map for that, sure. But you could also just slap a few `<a style="opacity: 0;">` tags on the page, with css to position them. Exactly the same end result, with cleaner code that's easier for screen readers/search engines to understand. Best of all, you don't have to learn some obscure html tag if you go with css on an <a> tag.